# Catch unchecked exceptions in java

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm writing application and I need to catch all existing exceptions including checked and uncheked exceptions. Is it possible to catch unchecked exceptions before application is terminated and write them in file for example?

Answer (score 2):

Both `Error` and `Exception` extend `Throwable`:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  try {
    new Test().test();
  } catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace(System.err);
  }
}
```

From the point made by @u6f6o - You should only do this in `main` because some of the `Throwable`s (e.g. `OutOfMemoryError`) mean that your JVM is probably in a very shaky state.

Comment: Catching Throwable is pretty ugly. Errors like OutOfMemoryError also extend Throwable and it's highly recommended to not catch them since your JVM is probably in an unstable state after this error raised.

Comment: can i also catch exceptions without writing try/catch in my code?

Comment: @u6f6o - Agreed - which is why I only ever do this in `main` to make sure I see them. If I am running as a service these would be lost.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler
```

see:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/thread_setdefaultuncaughtexceptionhandler.htm
or http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/exceptions/exceptions_uncaught_handler.shtml

Comment: +1 for answer that allow him to create custom handler for each thread's exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Catching unchecked exceptions in Java can be more tricky than it appears as they are Runtime exceptions. But, remember you don't have to catch runtime/unchecked exceptions; only checked exceptions. It is a bad practice, but virtually all of them `extend Throwable` and using `catch Throwable` might be a way to do this. However, you may want to have a look at the following documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

If you would like to write them into a file in Android, then within the catch block, you would have to obtain the exception message and write that message (a String) into the file, using one of the FileWriter APIs for Android. But remember, the catch bock should catch all Exceptions of type `Throwable`, even though this can be really ugly, as this will cover most unchecked exceptions in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Exception` class to catch your exceptions (this class is parent) and put it into a data structure in way of storing them and then, write them in a File.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Exception.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html

Answer (score 0):

You can catch unchecked exception in catch block.

like

```
try {
            int i = 9 / 0;

        } catch (ArithmeticException d) {
            d.printStackTrace();
        }
```